# How to evaluate a DCG parser/generator in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm having trouble understanding the syntax and use of DCG in Prolog. The code I'm working with is a type of parser for a grammar of the kind "a=1*2+(3-4)/5", here's a selection of it:

```
factor(factor(N)) --> int(N).

int(N):- number(N), N > 0, N < 10.
```

When running it, it looks like this

```
| ?- int(8).

yes

| ?- factor(8).

! Existence error in user:factor/1

! procedure user:factor/1 does not exist

! goal:  user:factor(8)

| ?- factor([],[],[]).

no
```

So factor wants 3 arguments. However, I cannot understand what these arguments are meant to represent, nor what I need to put in to make the query say 'yes'?

Comment: What's the purpose/meaning of `factor(factor(N)) --> int(N).`?

Comment: It's a part of a parser (for mathematical assignments, like a = 1 +4), a factor could be just an int, or a factor could be an expression within parenthesis (an expression could be a term, or a term plus/minus another expression, etc).

I only cut out this part because I didn't understand it.

Comment: The three arguments are 1. your output, that you define in the rule, 2. the input list of tokens, and 3. the output list of tokens (ie `[]`).

Comment: Say: `phrase(factor(X), L)`

Answer (score 0):

To run a DCG parser you will need to use either `phrase/2` or `phrase/3`:

```
phrase(factor(8), Text).
phrase(factor(N), "123", Rest).
```

Third argument of `phrase` is the unconsumed rest of the input (or possible complement of the output considering DCG's generative skills).

Comment: Sorry for necro, but this is quite important question